# How I can emit blob video from socket.io>3ver.?

Tags: socket.io

I found such a problem in the socket.io version> 3 in the socket.emit("blob", blob) where the blob is video data captured from the camera. The new version gives the transport error.
The old version (2.3) works without problems. I'm sorry, maybe I misunderstood something )

OS:Ubuntu 20.04 64bit
Browser:Cromium,Firefox
Back Node.js 10.19.0 socket.io latest->bug(2.3 work)
Front React 17.0.1 socket.io-client latest->bug(2.3 work)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the reason is. When opening a socket, you can specify maxHttpBufferSize: 1e8, you need to increase the size of this buffer, to transfer data more than 1MB, since by default it was reduced to 1e6 and if the data is more than 1MB, then the socket breaks the connection